# Datamining using holidays

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

**My setup:**

I am currently running a `SQLServer 2012` database paired with a `SSAS`.
My database features sales per store at specific times.

**My goal:**

I am interested in predicting future sales (amounts) for each store on an hourly basis.
Utilizing my base tables and creating a time series works out fine but I'm trying to factor in the sales that might occur during holidays. (Christmas sales etc)

**My question:**

Thinking one step ahead: say that I know I have sales inventory left over, they will go on increased discount right after the holidays(or say that older stock needs to get out so I can make space for holiday stock) How would I be able to have SSAS account for this added logic?

My reasoning tells me that I could include my second table in my mining model and use the `isHoliday` flag as an input for my sales prediction, however would the `SSAS` algorithms be smart enough to recognize patterns that occur before or after these dates and attribute them to the presence of this flag?

**My tables look like this:**

```
   Store_Id  |  TimeIndex  |  salesCount  |
-------------+-------------+--------------+
    1        |  01-01-2014 |  23          |
    1        |  02-01-2014 |  33          |
    2        |  03-01-2014 |  13          |
    3        |  01-01-2014 |  88          |


   TimeIndex  |  isHoliday |
--------------+------------+
   01-01-2014 |   yes      |
   02-01-2014 |   no       |
   03-01-2014 |   no       |
```